# Deploy on Elastick Beanstack (Tomcat) index page not served

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I'm trying to load my Spring Boot REST application on amazon AWS, specifically I'm using the Elastick Beanstack service.

I can configure everything correctly, but the public address (http://socialnotes-env-tomcat.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/) does not serve the index html page. In local with

> java -jar ...... snapshot.war

everything works correctly, but on amazon aws it seems not to find the index page (even if decompressing the war I see it in the main folder)

It seems very strange and I can not solve, the endpoints seem to work properly and I can also access the static files (http://socialnotes-env-tomcat.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/assets/images/coffee.jpg)

I followed this guide to create the war file: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/

But I can not in any way make the index page return, I always get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look in "Logs" of your project at AWS what caused the problem? You can choose option "Last 100 lines" and scrole down. That may help or at least may give some clues.

Comment: I looked at it, everything seems to work correctly except that every time I request a page I get a 404 error

Comment: I think I have identified the problem, with java -jar ....file.war works correctly locally, but renaming the file in jar (as I read that does aws) and throwing it java -jar ...name.jar I get the same error of 404 in loop that gives me aws. And the jar I can not fill it out.

Comment: Could it be something then there that something in your war files isn't in in correct war structure and, for example, your index.html is not right place there?

Comment: Like index.html should be in parent directory and your java classes  in WEB-INF/classes/ directory?And your java classes  in WEB-INF/classes/ directory?